# How can I make hamster switch activity when I switch workspaces?

Tags: hamster

Hamster seems to have an option that allows it to automatically switch activity whenever the workspace is switched.

However I can only configure Workspace 1, and even so it doesn't work (I'm using Unity on 12.04).

Answer (score 2):

This is a [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hamster-applet/+bug/529687). Also [reported upstream](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=623717) to Gnome. Who blamed Compiz. I haven't found a bug report for Compiz. The sole developer on Compiz [stopped](http://smspillaz.wordpress.com/2012/12/24/sideways/), so I think we're stuck there for now.

Not really answer, but a state of the situation. I'm not aware of any other time trackers that do allow workspace tracking on Compiz.